# Duplicate flat concrete roof questions

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I am looking for a solution for waterproofing flat concrete deck/roof and found there are several duplicates questions.  As I don't do a lot on this site, I am just bringing it your attention on how you want to proceed.

Duplicates:

- [What's a good way to seal a flat concrete roof?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/890/whats-a-good-way-to-seal-a-flat-concrete-roof)
- [What can I use to seal section of concrete roof?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/119802/what-can-i-use-to-seal-section-of-concrete-roof)
- [What is the method to seal a concrete roof?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21436/what-is-the-method-to-seal-a-concrete-roof)
- [How should I waterproof a concrete roof?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29976/how-should-i-waterproof-a-concrete-roof)

Slightly related probably not a dupe [Can a completely flat roof be waterproof?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/can-a-completely-flat-roof-be-waterproof/3793#3793)